# Solr Range, Returning Results Outside of Range

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm doing a Solr query on a range of values, and for whatever reason, some of my results are outside of my queries range. This seems to work like 75% of the time, but the other 25% seems to be like way off. Why is this?

[image: Solr returning results outside of query range.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is defined as a string. If you're comparing strings, `25.0` comes after `249`, since the `4` vs the `5` is the sorting criteria.

Define the field as [a double field or floating point field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/field-types-included-with-solr.html) and reindex your content. Remember that doubles or floats aren't exact, so if you require *exact* values, multiply the values by 100 when indexing and store them as integers (or use a currency field, but that field type brings a few other features as well).

Comment: This is what I was leaning to as well. Thanks.